# How can I parse different json urls when clicking on an item in a listview?

Tags: android, parsing, listview

So my code consist of parsing json urls and getting the values from the rotten tomato api. What I cant figure out is how to have a list view and when a users clicks on box office they should parse through the box office api. If a users clicks on upcoming movies than that url should be parsed. Parse works just need to fix my listview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String boxOfficeUrl ="http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?page_limit=50&page=1&country=us&apikey=arjrkxx65yxywyefb8g2xxhs";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new AsyncBox().execute(boxOfficeUrl);

}

protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result){

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking about a listview click listener or how to populate one?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ArrayList <String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new AsyncBox().execute(boxOfficeUrl);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> result){
    adapter.addAll(result);
}
```